# Building tree from specific list

Tags: haskell

What's the best way to build tree from list? I'm interested to find functional way to solve this problem. What packages and modules can help?

This question is about actually storing initial structure into a tree, not only displaying it as tree.

Initial structure:

```
[[1, 1, 1, 0.5],
 [1, 1, 2, 0.5],
 [1, 1, 3, 0.5],
 [1, 1, 4, 0.5],
 [1, 1, 5, 0.5],
 [1, 2, 1, 0.5],
 [1, 2, 2, 0.5],
 [1, 2, 3, 0.5],
 [1, 2, 4, 0.5],
 [1, 2, 5, 0.5]]
```

Result (typed by hands):

```
Node 1
    Node 1
        Node 1
            Node 0.5
        Node 2
            Node 0.5
        Node 3
            Node 0.5
        Node 4
            Node 0.5
        Node 5
            Node 0.5
    Node 2
        Node 1
            Node 0.5
        Node 2
            Node 0.5
        Node 3
            Node 0.5
        Node 4
            Node 0.5
        Node 5
            Node 0.5
```

Thank you!

Comment: When you say build tree, are you asking about storing it in a tree structure or actually displaying it as a tree like in your question?

Comment: I'm asking about actually storing initial structure into a tree. Thank you. Added to a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Define some tree structure

```
data T a = T a [T a] deriving Show
```

and insert each row into

```
insert :: Eq a => [T a] -> [a] -> [T a]
insert ts [] = ts
insert [] (x:xs) = [T x $ insert [] xs]
insert (t@(T n ns):ts) xss@(x:xs)
    | n == x    = (T n (insert ns xs)):ts
    | otherwise = t: insert ts xss
```

many rows to tree

```
fromList :: Eq a => [[a]] -> [T a]
fromList = foldl insert []
```

to print

```
showTree :: Show a => [T a] -> [String]
showTree ts = concat [ ("Node " ++ show n): map ("  "++) (showTree ns) | T n ns <- ts]
```

example

```
main = do
    putStrLn $ unlines $ showTree  $ fromList
        [[1, 1, 1, 0.5],
         [1, 1, 2, 0.5],
         [1, 1, 3, 0.5],
         [1, 1, 4, 0.5],
         [1, 1, 5, 0.5],
         [1, 2, 1, 0.5],
         [1, 2, 2, 0.5],
         [1, 2, 3, 0.5],
         [1, 2, 4, 0.5],
         [1, 2, 5, 0.5]]
```

resulting

```
Node 1.0
  Node 1.0
    Node 1.0
      Node 0.5
    Node 2.0
      Node 0.5
    Node 3.0
      Node 0.5
    Node 4.0
      Node 0.5
    Node 5.0
      Node 0.5
  Node 2.0
    Node 1.0
      Node 0.5
    Node 2.0
      Node 0.5
    Node 3.0
      Node 0.5
    Node 4.0
      Node 0.5
    Node 5.0
      Node 0.5
```

Comment: Exactly! Thanks. Initial lists will be like paths in a tree needed to insert by them?

Answer (score 3):

This is sometimes called a rose tree, [Data.Tree](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers/docs/Data-Tree.html) from the containers package (which comes with GHC) provide a type definition and some tools to handle those (very simple but since you already have them...).

You can do the job by inserting repeatedly each path but this would not take advantage of the structure of your list. If you're guaranteed that it is sorted, you can directly generate the Tree (or rather Forest since there's no guarantee all your sublist have the same head) by grouping your sublist by similar heads then generating the sub-forests from the tails recursively :

```
fromSortedList :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> Forest a
fromSortedList [] = []
fromSortedList xs = concatMap fromOneGroup . groupBy eq $ xs
  where
    eq (x:_) (y:_) = x == y
    eq _     _     = False
    fromOneGroup ([] : _) = []
    fromOneGroup xs       = [Node (head . head $ xs) (fromSortedList . map tail $ xs)]
```

You should probably benchmark this to be certain it's faster than the repeated insert.

Comment: Thanks! This way is interesting too.